# Use string name to access class properties

Tags: c#, reflection

How can I use a string variable to get the properties associated with a given class? If I use the class name as in the following:-

```
  PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo = typeof(Treblet).GetProperties();
```

where `Treblet` is the class name then I can get the number of properties for the class. But how can I replace the name of the class with a string variable? Thanks for all and any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string typeToSearchFor = "Treblet";
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo = 
     Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(
         t => t.Name == typeToSearchFor).FirstOrDefault().GetProperties();
```

This should do the trick.  You will need to search the assembly that the type is defined in.  For simplicity I've just searched the executing assembly.

Note Name is just the name of the type and FullName is the name of the type fully namespaced.

Comment: Thats a lovely line of code, in fact it was just the line of code I was trying to create myself but couldn't ; many many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a step back - the problem isn't getting properties, it's getting a `Type` value on which to call `GetProperties`. For that, you want [`Assembly.GetType(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb.aspx) or [`Type.GetType(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx). In both cases you need the namespace-qualified name, e.g. `System.Guid` rather than just `Guid`.

If you use `Type.GetType(string)` with *just* a namespace-qualified name, it will only check in mscorlib and the calling assembly - you'll need an assembly-qualified name to find a type in a different assembly.